# Wired LAN Conncetion not working, but router says I am connected

Tags: networking, network-manager, lan

I already looked for other questions maybe answering this, but nothing really seems to apply here. After a fresh install of 12.04, I can't get a wired connection established. WLAN works fine. What really surprises me is that my router interface shows that I am connected over LAN.

So how do I find out whats wrong here?

Don't know where to look further, but here is some relevant inforamation.

(To be exact regarding the history of this: I had a working installation of 12.04 before, then I got problems with the networking a day ago, and there was WLAN and LAN affected. After some attempts to fix this, I decided to do a fresh install. But now I am stuck in this situation, which is basically better because now I am at least able to connect over wifi.)

```
$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 20:cf:30:67:3f:5f  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::22cf:30ff:fe67:3f5f/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:791 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:1
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:163547 (163.5 KB)


$ nmcli dev list iface eth0   

GENERAL.GERÄT:                        eth0
GENERAL.TYP:                            802-3-ethernet
GENERAL.HERSTELLER:                     Atheros Communications Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUKT:                        AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
GENERAL.TREIBER:                        atl1c
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         20:CF:30:67:3F:5F
GENERAL.STATUS:                         30 (nicht verbunden)
GENERAL.GRUND:                          0 (Kein Grund angegeben)
GENERAL.UDI:                     /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:05:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.NM-VERWALTET:                   ja
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-FEHLT:                 nein
GENERAL.VERBINDUNG:                     nicht verbunden
CAPABILITIES.TRÄGERFREQUENZERKENNUNG: ja
CAPABILITIES.GESCHWINDIGKEIT:           100 Mb/s
WIRED-PROPERTIES.TRÄGERFREQUENZ:      an
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've entered "ifconfig" command, I've got like below.

```
root@ubuntuz:~# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:31:6b:c7:58
          inet addr:192.168.113.251  Bcast:192.168.113.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::217:31ff:fe6b:c758/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:239282389 errors:0 dropped:29137 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:135445065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:582201548 (582.2 MB)  TX bytes:2195333453 (2.1 GB)
          Interrupt:23 Base address:0xe000
```

Differences between you and me is that i have a ip address. 
Did you setup your ip address?? or DHCP is running on your network??

As you said, router interface shows everything is well, I think it will be enough if ip address is configured.

Comment: Normally,I use DHCP, which worked perfectly before and is also configured now, but it stopped working before reinstall, and also doesn't work after reinstall. The difference is, my Wifi Connection works now, but didn't before reinstall, so I guess, thats different problems before and after reinstall. Therefore problably not a Hardware Problem.